# how to check my sites final Ip and routes to that IP

Tags: wordpress, ip, hosting

Hi my site is a wordpress self hosted site   sussex chef dot com.

My problem is this: I use a word press help company that complete wordpress task via tickets.

I asked them to make some changes to my CSS but when they tried to make the changes via ftp they came back to say that the Cpanel account details I gave them do not appear to make changes for my site as follows:

> Hi ben

Unfortunately, the details you have submitted is not where your website > > resides. For example, I have created a file called junnel.txt, see link deleted as I have low reputation, however, it is not existing when I checked it, see .

Another example is, I added a CSS property but it is not showing when I checked the file, see link deleted as I have low reputation.

We suggest that you contact your hosting provider to make sure that your website really resides with them. Currently, your website's IP address is 104.25.159.28, see link deleted as I have low reputationwhile the details you've given, it is not (185.26.149.44), see link deleted as I have low reputation.

You can check your website info here - Who is. It might help you remember if you move your website to another hosting or not.

Once you have the correct details, please update your info here -

Please how do I check where my site is being served from? How do I make sure my site is being served from where it should be?

Sorry this is probably a complete novice question and I would be greatful for any help, especially in laymans terms.

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.whois.net/

shows www.sussexchef.com is registered with GoDaddy.com, that doesn't mean GoDaddy is hosting your server just that you registered your site name with them.

When I put in the name server PLESKDNS.CO.UK in whois.com it shows the registrant as Storm Internet Limited.  If GoDaddy isn't your host perhaps it is them?

Ping returns 198.105.244.114 as the IP for www.sussexchef.com.

Hope this helps.

```
Domain Name: SUSSEXCHEF.COM
Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 146
Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com
Name Server: NS17.PLESKDNS.CO.UK
Name Server: NS18.PLESKDNS.CO.UK
Status: clientDeleteProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientRenewProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 03-may-2015
Creation Date: 26-apr-2010
Expiration Date: 26-apr-2019
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I mangaged to prove that the Cpannel account was correct by upoading an image, the problem is now that when they upoad files and then try to navigate them via the browser they get a 404 instead of the intended file. I will start a new thread